# Entity Framework async Select/"Convert"-Func

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous

We are using the Entity Framework to access the database. The names in our database are very misleading therefore we used Func to map our database tables to better named model classes. And it's also very useful when you don't want to select all columns of a table.

Our database access methods look like:

```
var result = db.TABLE_NAME
.Where(x => x.TABLE_ID == id)
.AsQueryable()
.Convert(convertFunc)
.FirstOrDefault(); // or .ToList()
```

Convert is an extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Convert<TSource, T>(this IQueryable<TSource> query, Func<TSource, T> selectExpr)
{
    return query.Select(selectExpr).AsQueryable();
}
```

convertFunc is a method like the following:

```
internal static Func<TABLE_NAME, XxxModel> ToModel = x =>
x == null ? null : new XxxModel(true)
{
    Id = x.TABLE_ID,
    Name = x.TABLE_NAME,
    ...
}
```

This is working perfectly fine with synchronous calls, but we now want to change it to asynchronous calls. But this is not working.

```
var result = db.TABLE_NAME
.Where(x => x.TABLE_ID == id)
.AsQueryable()
.Convert(convertFunc)
.FirstOrDefaultAsync(); // or .ToListAsync()
```

The error message says that "IQueryable-Source does not implement IDbAsyncQueryProvider". Only provider which implement IDbAsyncQueryProvider can be used in asynchronous Entity Framework actions". How can we archieve this?

Comment: Huh, one of the advantages of using an ORM like EF is to provide mapping between database names and object names. Why would you create something yourself for that?

Comment: The names in our database are very bad (german shortcuts..), and I have no possibility to change that. And a big advantage I see: We don't need to select all the columns of a table everytime, which is a huge benefit performance wise.

Comment: What .Net framework and EF versions are you using?

Comment: .NET 4.6 and EF 6.1.3

Comment: The need of `AsQueryable` indicates a design problem. Changing  `Func<...>` to `Expression<Func<...>>` should solve it.

Comment: Is it code first, model first or database first?

Comment: But note that EF requires parameterless constructors, so you'll need to work on your `XxxModel` classes as well to make them compatible for EF query projection.

Comment: @PeterBons: it's database first.

Comment: @IvanStoev: We have parameterless constructors. I'll try it using Expressions later.